# How to remove a specific item from ListView and SharedPreferences?

Tags: java, android, listview, sharedpreferences

I save History items (words) to SharedPreferences, and History is well loaded to view in a ListView. I then use these code lines to delete a specific item from the ListView:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.edit:
            editNote(info.id);
            return true;
        case R.id.delete:
            String content = (String) mLSTHistory.getItemAtPosition(info.position);
               aptList.remove(content);
               aptList.notifyDataSetChanged();
            deleteNote(info.id);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
private void deleteNote(long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (prefs.getBoolean("saveHistory", true) && mWordHistory != null && mWordHistory.size() >= 1)

    prefs =   PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    StringBuilder sbHistory = new StringBuilder();
    for (String item : mWordHistory)
    {
        sbHistory.append(item);
        sbHistory.append(",");

    String strHistory = sbHistory.substring(0, sbHistory.length()-1);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    //editor.remove(content);
    editor.putString("history", strHistory);
    editor.commit();
    }
}
private void editNote(long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

The selected item is definetely removed from the ListView, but it is not deleted from SharedPreferences in which it is saved. Consequently, when the Listview is re-loaded, the item is still there.

**My question is: *how can I code to remove the selected item from SharePreferences as well?* I mean *how can I do to remove the selected item from both ListView and SharedPreferences?***

It would be great if you could provide instructions based on my code as I'm quite new with Android. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To clear shared prefrences, Use

```
editor.clear();
editor.commit();
```

Also if, i have got your question correctly. To check if a value is stored in shared preferences, do this

```
SharedPreferences mySharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences", 0);
                if(mySharedPrefs.contains("theKey")) {
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                editor.remove("thekey");
                editor.commit();
}
```

Comment: Many thanks to you. My problem is how to define `theKey`, which is the item removed from the ListView. This item can be any word shown in the ListView. So how to inform SharedPreferences of this item?

Comment: Defining the value for the preference key is simple. You use `editor.putString(key, value);` to assign a key to a value right? so as the code above, we are checking if the preference really contains a preference/value. Read this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#remove(java.lang.String) and this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#contains(java.lang.String) for more clarifications. If this helped you, please ACCEPT THE ANSWER. Thanks

Comment: Although I haven't still sorted my problem out, I think it's my limited Java knowledge to blame for it. Your support is an answer anyway. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
editor.remove("UserName");
editor.clear();
editor.putString("history",strHistory);   
editor.commit();
```

Comment: @Dipak Keshariya: Thank you very much. I think my problem is how to define `"UserName"`. I mean UserName here is the item that is removed from the ListView, but the removed item can be any word in the list.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.
Basically what you have to do is remove that particular item from your list view and then again add that updated list in sharedpreference so it will override the shared preference.

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            addPlace.remove(i);
            
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            try {
                sharedPreferences.edit().putString("places", ObjectSerializer.serialize(MainActivity.addPlace)).apply();  add the updated shared pref again that will override previous saved.

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return false;
        }
    });
```